# JSException while loading a file in a codemirror based editor using java using setvalue

Tags: javafx, codemirror

I have a java based application that reads a file and displays the same in a code mirror based editor. The java code reads a file selected by user and converts it into string. The string is then passed to the editor using 'editor.setvalue'. The problem is that any hardcoded string is displayed fine. But if it is read from a file then I get an error

```
Caused by: netscape.javascript.JSException: SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF
```

I am able to print the file properly, no issues in that.

This is what I am trying to do in java.

```
String sb = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
webengine.executeScript("editor.setValue('" + sb + "');");
```

"webengine.executescript" is a javafx way of calling a javascript function visible to the html rendered in the webengine.

My code Mirror code.

```
<form>
    <textarea id="code" name="code">
    </textarea>
</form>
<script>
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
        lineNumbers : true,
        matchBrackets : true,
        mode : "text/x-java",
        theme : "theme_value",
        indentUnit : 4,
        gutter: true
    });
</script>
```

I am not able to understand which all characters are causing this issue. 
I tried adding two strings using "+" operator and the added strings were displayed. But, when I insert a newline "\n" between the strings , I start getting the same error.I tried replacing the newline with 
, but not much of help as they were displayed as it is without breaking the line.

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that when calling `executeScript` if the passed in String into the given Javascript method contains any newline characters or single quotes then that will result in the syntax error.

Quick fix:

```
    content = content.replace("'", "\\'");
    content = content.replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "\\n");
    content = content.replace("\n", "\\n");
    content = content.replace("\r", "\\n");
```

That way the newlines and single quotes will be preserved in the JavaScript method.